# my index dont include submit page that is in same folder

Tags: php, submit, plesk

my index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Primjer forme s submit poljem</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="submit.php" method="post">
    <label for="name">Ime:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
    <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Pošalji">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

my submit.php

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $name = $_POST["name"];
  $email = $_POST["email"];
  echo "Ime: " . $name . "<br>";
  echo "Email: " . $email;
}
?>
```

my submit.php is

booth file are in the ame folder

my hosting is with plesk interface

error is file not found. please help

i am not sure if this is correct code is it maybe problem with my plesk?

Comment: I remember that recently there has been an issue with Nginx and password protection. When files are smaller 1023 bytes and password protection is on for the website, Nginx responds with a 404 error. Do you happen to have password protection enabled?